# Which resource spawns where?

Tags: rust

I am aware in general sense what kind of items I can find in towns, containers, red creatures, animals, piles etc..

What I want to know is where exactly in the map to these spawn and what are their spawn density?

Some 100 m2 place has 4 resource spawns. Another 20 m2 place has 8 resource spawns. I want to find the dense spawn spots.

Basically I am looking for a map like this, which indicates, **exactly** where an item spawns its yield amount and what it is.
http://dayzdb.com/map/chernarusplus

Comment: As far as I know it is random.  However resources do not spawn in wastelands.  Rad animals (Red ones that drop loot) only spawn in specific areas though.

Answer (score 1):

Resources have certain areas to spawn, although within these areas they spawn in a random location inside the area boundaries. so for example north north-east of split rad there is a location called next valley, in this location i believe it is the most densely spawning location for metal piles and wood piles... it is hard to find a map for these locations seeming how everyone calls areas different things (every makes code names for places within a squad).

in the link below this is a map that shows different locations. on the north of the map you will see next valley if you are looking for a place to make a base this is a good location, although you will have to look out for other people. this place is kinda high traffic.

[Click to go to map](https://rustmap.net/)

hope this helped, this information has come from my experiences in the game, 300+ hours if you were wondering.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of rare red/yellow boxes in Big Rad Town. 
Generally, common green boxes spawn in the abandoned buildings scattered across the map (but watch your rads) and wood piles and rocks spawn randomly. 
Also, since rust is only availible on multiplayer, the best place to loot is always Hacker Valley. The only houses there are the ones of hackers, and with a few c4's you could probably get in one of those. Help your community, raid the hackers :D

Answer (score 0):

The spawn rate of minerals (as of yet) is random. The minerals can spawn wherever the random generator puts them. They can spawn right next to a player, they can spawn nowhere near a player. According to the wiki: `Wood piles can be found everywhere around the map of Rust.` and  `Rocks can be found everywhere around the map of Rust.`

---

**Personal experience**

Through personal experience i've noticed that allot of resource nodes tend to be rather far away from the cities. Now since they can actually respawn near cities (and partially in some (big radtown)) far away from cities is simply the place where not a lot of players look. In my experience, resource nodes have a percentage to respawn. To explain this, if you completely deplete some rocks of its resource there is a random chance that either a rock or a wood pile spawns back. The type and location is random.

Comment: that is false, wood and rocks cannot be found everywhere.

Comment: This is the information that the wiki provides. I can add in some personal experience but besides that its all science and testing i'm afraid.